# Composer Installed Package with WordPress Rest API Endpoint

Tags: api

I have a WordPress website. I installed composer into my Root Directory before the "www" directory. I installed the Square SDK.

I have a WordPress Page which a person enters their C/C details to make a purchase, but I need to make a Fetch (JavaScript) to a PHP Endpoint to use the Square SDK.

I decided to create a Custom Endpoint in WordPress. I made a new plugin folder in my WordPress plugins folder called "ant-square-sdk", and inside of the "ant-square-sdk" folder I created a file called "ant-square-sdk.php".

Inside the "ant-square-sdk.php" file, I made a PHP require to the autoload.php of the composer.

But, when calling the Square SDK classes - I get an error.

**`"Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'use' (T_USE) in"`**

Comment: What error? When? Sorry, but the question as written doesn't provide nearly enough information for anyone to be able to assist. You'll need to include code and exactly what messages you're receiving.

Comment: @JacobPeattie - I updated the description of my questions. Thank you for the help!

Comment: That error seems to be a simple syntax error, rather than anything to do with the SDK. If I had to guess you're missing a `;` at the end of a line.